# Add to Home Screen dialog box not showing in my site

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I setup Progressive web app in my [site](https://news.justinechacko.in). The site is showing A2HS default notification in bottom screen in mobile devise. I also need to setup a "Add to Home Screen dialog box" in browser. I used the code like below in main.js file of website.

```
let deferredPrompt;

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
// Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
  btnAdd.style.display = 'block';
});


btnAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
  btnAdd.style.display = 'none';
  // Show the prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice
    .then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});
```

But the dialog box not showing in browser and I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: btnAdd is not defined

in the console. Do I need to add btnAdd element anywhere in the website?
My site [sw.js](https://news.justinechacko.in/sw.js)

Comment: You need to get the button. You can't arbitrarily call a variable name without declaring it regardless of it the element may or may not exist in the html. Do you have a button declared in your site? This code isn't going to autogen one so you still need to declare it and pull it.

Comment: How to show dialog box on load of web page?

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me.
js

```
    let deferredPrompt;
    window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {
  // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
  e.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
  document.getElementById("pwaa").style.display = 'block';
});
    document.getElementById("pwaa").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
  document.getElementById("pwaa").style.display = 'none';
  // Show the prompt
  deferredPrompt.prompt();
  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
  deferredPrompt.userChoice
    .then((choiceResult) => {
      if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      deferredPrompt = null;
    });
});
```

html

```
<button id="pwaa">App</button>
```